# How to get max ID to String from Firebase Firestore to Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating Student Registration system using flutter and firebase. I need to create new Student ID using last Student ID that I saved to database. For that I need to get max/latest value of Student Id from firebase database and I need it return to String for using anywhere in my code.

[image]

I tested using init print, but out put is just [] only

Comment: Where do you call `getDocId()`?

Comment: getDocID() call within init for now to test

Comment: At this point the future will not be completed yet. Use a `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: There could be a whole bunch of reasons the array is not being populated; the `user` collection may not exist, the `sid` field may not exist, does `document.reference.id` produce anything? You may not be authenticated. There could be rules in place preventing the read. There's no error handling in the code so you'll never know about any errors. When posting questions, please do some troubleshooting first to narrow down the cause. Oh and don't post pics of code, post the code itself.